# Does uniform convergence of a sequence of functions imply uniform convergence of a subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that if a sequence of real numbers converges then all subsequences converge and all convergent subsequences converge to the same limit. But does this apply to sequences of functions and do the subsequences converge uniformly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f_{k_n}$ is a subsequence of $f_n$ then for every $x$, $f_{k_n}(x)$ is a subsequence of $f_n(x)$, so $f_{k_n}(x)\to f(x)$ since a subsequence of a convergent sequence also converges to the same limit, so that $f_{k_n} \to f$ as well.

$f_n \to f$ uniformly means $\forall \epsilon>0~\exists N ~ \forall x ~\forall n>N ~|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

The convergence of $f_{k_n}$ is also uniform since $\forall \epsilon>0~\exists N ~ \forall x ~\forall n>N ~ |f_{k_n}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$, because by $f_n\to f$ uniformly we know there's such $N$ so that whenever $n > N$ we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$, and we know that $k_n$ is an increasing sequence of natural numbers so that $k_n \geq n$ so that $n>N$ implies $k_n > N$.